# How can I add value to my fields in database

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to change field values in database but there are not any option to do that as you see in the picture below (I'm using mamp in Mac os Catalina), there aren't any option, this is picture of my problem:
[image: this is picture of my problem]
  I want to know how can I add the options, I will upload another picture below for to understand what I want to do
I want to have these options:
[image: I want to have these options]

Comment: Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RMgMI3ONrI

Answer (score 0):

These options are based on the primary key. If your table or even your SELECT query doesn't have a primary key, you will not have this first column with these buttons.

Comment: thank you very much , tried that , you are true.